# Dart Fold method error - Summing a list int

Tags: dart

I'm getting error summing a List using the .fold() method:

```
List<int> listInt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
int sumList = listInt.fold(0, (p, c) => p + c);

// First Print  
print(sumList);

// Second Pring
print(listInt.fold(0, (p, c) => p + c));
```

Printing sumList is perfectly fine, but when I print the same operation i get a compilation error:

```
The operator '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A case where the Dart type system is not smart enough to guess the correct type. What happens in your second line is that `fold` thinks you want a `Object?` returned so `p` becomes `Object?`.

In the first example, the Dart type system guesses the type based on the expected returned type which is `int` in your case. But because `print` expects `Object?`, you are really not getting the type you expect.

The reason is that the Dart type system does not really understand the concept of defining the returned type of a method given as second argument based on the type of the first argument. So `fold` is often problematic here if we don't have an typed output.

We can force it to understand what we want by changing your second line to:

```
print(listInt.fold<int>(0, (p, c) => p + c));
```

And it should work as you want.